# Why my code results in infinite loop?

Tags: python

I am novice to python. While I was trying to write simple code, I have faced a peculiar problem which I could not understand. Following is the code

```
def myLog(x, b):
    temp = b
    def mylog(x,b):
        while b <= x :
            mylog(x,b*temp)
        return b/temp - 1
    return mylog(x,b)
myLog(16,2)
```

Why does this code result in an infinite loop?

**EDIT:**
I found out the reason why it results in infinite loop. This is the modified code. I forget to use **return** statement inside the inner function definition

```
    def myLog(x, b):
        temp = b
        def mylog(x,b):
             while b <= x :
                  return mylog(x,b*temp)
             return b/temp - 1
        return mylog(x,b)
```

myLog(16,2)

Comment: Pleased indent the code properly. As it is now, this will not work. Python is whitespace sensitive.

Comment: why is this the 20th post since yesterday about finding the log with a while loop?

Comment: The infinite loops looks like it's because you're never changing the value of b inside `mylog`.

Comment: @JBernardo someone gave the whole class an assignment they can't solve

Comment: @Aniket I did not ask you give the solution.Because the solution is piece of cake. I just asked why it results in infinite loop. because the same approach in scala works fine,may be because of indetation problem.But because of I am novice to python not able to figure it out.

Comment: Please note that `while b <= x : return mylog(x,b*temp)` actually means `if b <= x : return mylog(x,b*temp)`

Comment: Thank you Vortexfive... Now I got it

Answer (score 2):

Neither `b` nor `x` is modified in the loop, so the comparison result will never change.

Comment: The value is not changed but I am passing the changed value as parameter => myLog(x,b*temp)